# How to suppress R startup message?

Tags: r

Running on Windows 7

```
rterm < foo.r > temp.txt
```

The output file starts with:

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
```

and further text.

How do I suppress this message? I did not see an option to do this in the Rprofile.site file. Of course I can use another program to delete the first N lines of the output file, but it is more elegant to suppress the startup message?

Comment: I usually make a shortcut for Rgui and then put this ` -q` on the end of the Target field when right clicking/properties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Invoking R from the command line](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line):

> ```
> --quiet
> --silent
> -q
> ```
>
> Do not print out the initial copyright and welcome messages.
>
> ```
> --slave
> ```
>
> Make R run as quietly as possible. This option is intended to support programs
>   which use R to compute results for them. It implies `--quiet` and `--no-save`.