# How to make RStudio start R console with --quiet?

Tags: r, rstudio

In question [How to suppress R startup message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489176/how-to-suppress-r-startup-message), starting `rterm` with `--quiet` will suppress the copyright and welcome messages. I wonder if I can do the same thing to the R Console started by RStudio?

Comment: You could add `cat("\014")` to your site or user profile file. That's the equivalent of typing CTRL+L to clear the screen. Thank this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16084793/1201032

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this in RStudio. Apparently it is on their "to do" list.

There are a couple references on the RStudio support site, stating the above.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200662563-pass-command-line-parameters-to-R-

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200662897-Pass-command-line-options-to-R