# Suppressing startup message from RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, startup, ubuntu-20.04

What can I do to suppress the startup message in RStudio?

I tried without success:

```
.First <- function(){cat("\014")}
```

Comment: Is [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26561313/8245406) a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, it is, thanks I didn't find this post.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Linux/Unix based system, you can make an alias in your ~/.bashrc file like so:

```
alias R="R -q"
```

Comment: It doesn't work in RStudio, but thank you anyway.