# How to remove R's startup messages in console mode?

Tags: r

Whenever we start R console with "R" command, we can see messages as follows

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16) -- "Full of Ingredients"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
```

I'd appreciate if someone let me know how can we disable it.

Comment: I don't know how you can systematically remove this introduction (or why you would need to) but you can make it disappear with `ctrl+L` each time you start R...

Comment: That's right. Well, the only reason is that it is sometimes annoying since it covers lots of space in the console.  Currently I removed texts in en.po file to handle this problem. But I do not think it is a nice way, for example, I need to do it repeatedly after each release. I am curious that may be there is another ways to do this. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress R startup message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489176/how-to-suppress-r-startup-message)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to run whichever executable you're using with the `--quiet` command line option (`--silent` or `-q` will also work). The exact details of how to accomplish that will depend on how you typically launch R.

From the command line of a machine with R on its path, just do:

```
R --quiet
```

Or if (for example) you want to set up a clickable icon for the Windows GUI that launches without the "greeting", you can:

1. Create a shortcut to the Rgui executable (stored in a path like `$R_DIRECTORY/bin/i386/Rgui.exe`).
2. Right-click on the shortcut and then select 'Properties'.
3. On the Shortcut tab, modify the 'Target' field to (the equivalent on your machine of) `C:\R\R-current\bin\i386\Rgui.exe --quiet`.
4. Modify the 'Start in' field as desired.