# Cleaning up the startup messages in the R console (.RProfile)

Tags: r

I'm currently writing a `.Rprofile`, and I can't seem to get rid of specific parts of the startup messages in the console.

First of all, I would like to either suppress or skip the version info at the start of a new R session.

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
```

[Another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489176/how-to-suppress-r-startup-message) showed how to suppress the message when starting R from the console, but is it also possible when loading a project inside RStudio? [Three years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561002/how-to-make-rstudio-start-r-console-with-quiet) someone said it was on the devs to-do-list.

I tried a different approach by beginning my `.Rprofile` with `cat("\014")` (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260340/function-to-clear-the-console-in-r)), but this somehow clears the console including messages that are printed afterwards.

Here's the relevant code:

```
cat("\014")

# A fun welcome message
message("Hi, welcome to your Data Analysis Project")

if(interactive()) 
  try(fortunes::fortune(), silent = TRUE)
```

With this, I end up with a completely empty console at startup.

Ultimately, I would like to end up with this console at startup:

```
Hi, welcome to your Data Analysis Project

Uwe Ligges: I just told nonsense, stepclass() does not make sense with
randomForest(), obviously ... (wonder why nobody shouted?).
Douglas Bates: Oh, we're just so used to you talking nonsense that we don't
bother to point it out any more :-)
   -- Uwe Ligges and Douglas Bates
      R-help (July 2005)
>
```